# Do use in PHP "use" for internal php classes or backslash "\"

Tags: php, coding-style, conventions

I wonder what the differences and consequences are in applying individual conventions.

I mean only the rule about internal classes of type DateTime, PDO, Exception etc.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Foo
{
    public function bar(\DateTime $baz): void
    {
    }
}
```

vs

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use DateTime;

class Foo
{
    public function bar(DateTime $baz): void
    {
    }
}
```

What are the arguments behind one or the other solution? Can you say that any solution is better?

Who use "\":

- Symfony
- Laravel

Who use "use":

- ?

Comment: Usually boils down to (cargo cult) coding styles and (fictual) microoptimization, unless there's a concrete identifier overlap.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using that imported class once, it's probably better to just call that class using `\`.

However, if you are using that class throughout your methods, it would make more sense to import it using `use`.

It's not framework-specific, it's case-dependant.

The reason for the `\` is because when you're in a namespace, it tries importing classes from the same namespace. Using `\` almost "resets" the namespace to top-level.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make any difference even if you use internal classes or not. 
When you import a class you should avoid leading backslash cause the path is supposed to be absolute

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php